# how do I add debug to my webpack config

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have moved one of my projects from browserify over to webpack, and I was just wondering how I add debug to the config file, similar to `browserify --debug` to give source mapping.

Here is my webpack.config file:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/js/main.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: './src/public/',
    publicPath: 'public'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader' }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: add this to your config *devtool: 'sourcemap'*

Comment: Thanks Jesús I just found it in the docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I just needed to add source mapping: `devtool: 'source-map'`

```
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: './src/js/main.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: './src/public/',
    publicPath: 'public'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader' }
    ]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **webpack version 4+** then add this config 
**devtool: 'inline-source-map'**
 in your `webpack.config.js`

For reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/